# Problems with HasSupportFragmentInjector in kotlin - DispatchingAndroidInjector is null

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm trying to implement mvp pattern with dagger 2 support in my app

Here's the objects:

```
class BaseApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector
{
    override fun onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate()
        initDi()
    }

    private fun initDi(){

        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this)
    }

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>
    {
        return activityInjector
    }
}

    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class))
    interface AppComponent
    {
        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder
        {
            @BindsInstance
            fun application(application: Application): Builder

            fun build(): AppComponent
        }

        fun inject(app: BaseApplication)
    }

    @Module
    class AppModule
    {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        internal fun provideContext(application: Application): Context
        {
            return application
        }
    }

    @Module
    abstract class ActivityBuilder
    {
        @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(LoginFragmentProvider::class))
        internal abstract fun bindAuthenticationActivity(): AuthenticationActivity
    }

    @Module
    public abstract class LoginFragmentProvider
    {
        @ContributesAndroidInjector
        abstract LoginFragment provideLoginFragmentFactory();
    }

    class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector
    {
        @Inject lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

        override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment>
        {
            return androidInjector
          }
    }

    class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onAttach(context: Context?)
        {
             AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
             super.onAttach(context)
        }
```

The problem is, when login fragment calls **AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)**, The AuthenticationActivity **supportFragmentInjector** get called, but the **androidInjector** is still null

As a result, I'm getting the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity .....AuthenticationActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property androidInjector has not been initialized

I'm not sure how to fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you building the Component in your `BaseApplication`?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, check the update

Comment: Create base activity/fragment and write inject code over there instead of writing on each activity and fragment.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Completely agreed. It's just for learning dagger purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forget to inject your `AuthenticationActivity`. You should call `AndroidInjection` in `onCreate`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

**Edit**: You can check my example repo for more information. https://github.com/savepopulation/dc-tracker

Comment: OMG your are the man! Shame on me for didn't see it. Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome. i'll be glad if you accept my answer. thanks.

Comment: Sure! in ac couple of minutes when i'll be able to :)